# Does /init (or /linuxrc) script creates temporary device nodes in /dev?

Tags: kernel, boot, block-device, initrd, initramfs

Considering that GRUB executes following lines:

```
kernel /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1 ro
initrd /initrd
```

On boot, how does the Linux kernel finds out about `/dev/sda1` device node?

I know that initrd/initramfs images contain modules for storage (etc.) devices, which are loaded into memory to enable access to the storage.  What bugs me, is how exactly the kernel parameter `root=/dev/sda1` is parsed by the kernel.

Does the `/init` (or `/linuxrc`) script in initrd/initramfs creates the `/dev` directory and then the device node `/dev/sda1` in it?  Or the "major" and "minor" numbers for `/dev/sda1` are hardcoded in the kernel?

Answer (score 3):

If you have an initramfs the kernel just unpacks and mounts the initramfs and executes `/init` afterwards. Everything else will be handled by the `/init` executable. This also means the kernel doesn't mount the device specified in the `root` boot parameter.

Different Distributions use different initramfs frameworks like e.g. [dracut](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Dracut) for Fedora or [initramfs-tools](http://wiki.debian.org/initramfs-tools) for Debian. Most common solutions are either using something like `udev`, `mdev` or `devtmpfs`. Some may also just use [`MAKEDEV`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_MAKEDEV.htm) to generate a static layout or have the device files already integrated into their image.

If you boot without an initramfs the kernel can just boot from devices with known major/minor numbers, e.g. `/dev/sda1` but not from lvm devices.

Answer (score 0):

The initial code runs a program called `mdev` which is basically a cut-down version of `udev`. This scans all the devices and creates the initial contents of the `/dev` folder. The kernel is then able to effectively execute `mount /dev/sda1 /` and start finding the full system.

See [here](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/docs/mdev.txt?h=1_18_stable) is you want to know more about `mdev`.

Major and minor device numbers are actually hardcoded into those kernel modules which are device drivers and which use static major numbers (see, for example, [Documentation/devices.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/devices.txt) in the kernel sources). Most (all?) disk driver kernel modules would fall into this category. So, as @Ulrich Dangel says, some kernels can boot without an initramfs/initrd as long as the needed modules are statically linked to the kernel image.

Comment: Just for the record this is implementation specific, Debian for example uses udev and doesn't use mdev

Answer (score 0):

The major any minor numbers of the root device are stored in the kernel image (see manpage of `rdev` for more information).

Yet, the kernel commandline arguments are NOT interpreted by the kernel. The initial ramdisk, initrd, contains a filesystem with a minimal linux which usually does the interpreting part. How the initrd works depends on your distribution. It may simply contain the node /dev/sda1 or some script/programm that creates it at runtime.

If you're on a Debian based Linux you can unpack your ramdisk like so:

```
mkdir /tmp/initrd
cd /tmp/initrd
zcat /boot/path/to/initrd | cpio -iv
```

The debian initrds are scripts and you can have a look at how it works. After the kernel has unpacked the initrd it launches the script `init` which you should now find in `/tmp/initrd`. Note the block where it says `for x in $(cat /proc/cmdline); do`.

In `/proc/cmdline` are the arguments passed using Grub (you can check/verify that right now with your shell!). If you care to dive a little deeper into Debians initrd you will note that you can make your kernel/initrd use a NFS share as root file system by passing the option `root=/dev/nfs` with Grub. When you do, no node `/dev/nfs` is created or mounted. It just tells the initrd what to do.

In the end every such initrd will run the command provided by some option like `init=` or the default `/sbin/init`

Coming back to your initial question in the headline: yes /init (most likely) creates that node at runtime. It uses all kinds of programms/heuristics/voodoo to figure out how to mount your root filesystem.

Comment: If the kernel can't execute (can't find) `/init`, it will parse `root=` parameter.  Reference: http://landley.net/writing/rootfs-howto.html